# Scala Import and Packages error

Tags: java, scala, import, package

I want to import and call a java class(which in from an external package ) from a scala object . My code is like this

Java code:

```
package com.test.services.account;

public class MyMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("coming into main");
    }
}
```

Scala code:

```
package com.newtest.newservice.scala
import _root_.com.test.services.account.MyMain

object scalatest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Hello, world! " + args.toList)
    // Deployer.main(args)
    val  de:MyMain  = new MyMain()
    println(de.toString())
  }
}
```

when i compile it using scalac scalatest.scala, it gives an error

**scalatest.scala:2: error: object test is not a member of package com
import *root*.com.test.services.account.MyMain
                  ^
one error found**

Could anybody guide me how can i import my java class into scala code ?

Thanks
Suresh

Comment: Are you sure that the Java classes are in the classpath of the Scala compiler? (In case you don't use it already: Sbt simplifies such things a lot and is in general a good choice.)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use something like sbt, you should first decide where your CLASSPATH is. Since you have two different class files (one generated from Java and one from Scala), you need at least one directory where your class files need to live. Let's say that is `d:\myclasses`.

In that case, you'd compile the java file using this command:

```
d:\mycode> javac -d d:\myclasses MyMain.java
```

This would generate your Java class file in the appropriate package structure at `d:\myclasses`. Then you would compile the scala file like so

```
scalac -classpath d:\myclasses -d d:\myclasses scalatest.scala
```

Instead of passing the classpath as part of the scalac command line, you could also set your `CLASSPATH` environment variable to `d:\myclasses`.

Comment: Hi Rajesh, i did that and but when i run the scala class i got this excepton

Comment: I did that and the error when i run the scala class:

C:>scala com\newtest\newservice\scala\scalatest Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com\newtest\newservice\scala\scalatest (wrong name: com/newtest/newservice/scala/scalatest)

scalatest is my coimplied scala class

any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: You're making the same mistake again. Scala (also the JVM) doesn't know what your classpath is, so it doesn't know where to find your classes. Either pass it on the commandline like for the scalac command, or set the CLASSPATH environment variable. Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29 to understand a little about what the CLASSPATH is, and why it is important.